# Using AlarmManager to print a message once a day

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I'm new to android development and I would like to know how to get the app to do a certain action at a certain time of each day. For example incrementing a counter every time it hits midnight. I spent quite some time yesterday looking into this but couldn't find anything straight forward.

Thanks

Comment: Have you implemented something, code? Tried any tutorials

Comment: I ended up getting this app installed on my device. https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm

Comment: As of right now, it doesn't do anything yet. Still trying to figure out how to get it to shoot a message at a certain time of the day.

Comment: It seems that I should probably look more into how intents work. That example seems to rely a lot on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the use of an AlarmManager the following Tutorial is very helpful

http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/